# VBA script to view mail item in preview pane

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there a way to view mail item in the preview pane. I searched and found the `mailitem.display` method but it opens mail in a separate window but i want to see it in preview pane.

Regards 
Saad

Comment: You can't do that easily. You have to create a preview pane with informations you want to display (To, Cc, Bcc, text) and dispatch those information in your preview pane
`previewPaneTo = mailitem.To`, `previewPaneCc = mailitem.Cc`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [AddToSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868732(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Explorer class. Don't forget to clear the [Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861267(v=office.15).aspx) object before using the **AddToSelection** method. The [ClearSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862680(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Explorer class cancels any selection in the active explorer. If the Reading Pane is visible and the current view is a table view, calling ClearSelection renders the Reading Pane blank.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using this code `Set eExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set eExplorer.CurrentFolder = _
                Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("SampleFolder")
            
            eExplorer.ClearSelection
            eExplorer.AddToSelection mailItem ` it works fine when i step into it one by one but when i use the button i added to the ribbon it raises [this error ](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/24060/20150804-heyl-63kb.jpg)